# Issue with using python3 join construct

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use `join` in `Python3` as shown below:

```
"".join([str(random.randint(0, sys.maxsize-1)) for i in 0,1,2])
```

Somehow this is not working. Can anyone spot the issue with the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is `for i in 0,1,2`. `0,1,2` doesn't represent anything that can be tested for collection membership by `in`, as it is not a sequence. If you surround it with a tuple or a list, or optimally in this case `range(3)`, you will no longer have an issue as now you have a sequence that can be tested for collection membership by `in`.

**Demo**:

```
>>> print("".join([str(random.randint(0, sys.maxsize-1)) for i in range(3)]))
83269163661531505224288232
```